# Does the nitrogen atom move with in the molecule in an ammonia maser, or does the molecule flip?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, rearrangements

This [intriguing answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/132930/16035) to *Can reactions produce microwave or radio wave radiation?* says (in part):

> An [ammonia maser](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_09.html) qualifies as an inorganic RF-emitting reaction. As the nitrogen changes position in the $\ce{NH3}$ molecule, ~24 GHz radiation is emitted.
>
> Similarly, organic methanol, $\ce{CH3OH}$ [makes a maser found in nature, emitting at ~36.2 GHz](https://phys.org/news/2017-08-astronomers-methanol-maser-emission-nearby.html) and also [at ~6.7 GHz](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014PASJ...66...31F/abstract)

The first link is to [The Ammonia Maser](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_09.html) in Feynman's Lectures on Physics and it includes a picture of a triangular pyramid with the nitrogen pointing "up" in one case and "down" in the other as an illustration of the transition.

But how does it get there? Does it "tunnel through" the nitrogen triangle, or does the whole molecule flip around? Can we even ask that question? Could we, if for example we labeled the corners with $\ce{{}^{1}H}$ $\ce{{}^{2}H}$ and $\ce{{}^{3}H}$ as a [gedankenexperiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment) to make the two distinguishable?

Comment: The nitrogen atom pierces the triangle of the hydrogen atoms to go on the other side. If you wanted to label something then it should be the hydrogen atoms. There is only one nitrogen atom. But if you arranged $\ce{^1H}$, $\ce{^2H}$, and $\ce{^3H}$ clockwise then you could tell if the nitrogen atom was above or below the triangle of hydrogen atoms.

Comment: @MaxW yikes $\ce{HN3}$! sorry about that. Because it's such a glaring error I'm going to fix the question accordingly. But *how does one know* that it pierces the triangle? Hopefully a posted answer will support it's postion. Thanks!

Comment: Consider the ammonia molecule stationary in its own frame of reference. With the emission or adsorption of a photon the center of gravity would have to recoil appropriately from the photon's momentum.

Comment: @MaxW That's always true for any system of atoms that emits a photon. A molecule will recoil after radiating a photon no matter what the nature of the transition nor of what if any internal rearrangement happens. If you know how it is known that the nitrogen pierces the triangle then pease consider writing that up as an answer where it can be voted on. Thanks!

Comment: Tunnelling occurs from one structure to the other and as a result the levels below the barrier are doubled. The double well potential and some energy levels is shown in this answer, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/132449/particle-in-a-box-with-different-barriers-between-two-molecules/132499#132499. The spectroscopic data shows that in ammonia the barrier is approx 2000 cm$^{-1}$. The N atom is 38 pm out of the plane of the 3 H atoms and the lowest energy transition is 0.97 cm${-1}$. see Swalen, J. D.; Ibers, J. A. J. Chem. Phys. 1966, 36, 1914 - 1918.

Comment: Thanks! I'm on a bus right now, [I see it](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1701290) in 1962, when I get to a library I'll see if I can access it. I wonder if in the following 60 years there's been any independent way to physically verify that this is really quantum mechanical tunneling proper without question, and all other possibilities have been ruled out, or if it's still "the numbers match so it must be right".

Comment: I think that even in 1966 the idea of tunnelling was at least 30 years old.  I think that spectroscopy is /was the way to test this. There are many other examples in molecules, also radioactivity and scanning tunnelling microscopes.

Comment: @porphyrin I'm familiar with electron tunneling in STM but when it's a complex system like a whole atom I guess I'm just curious how it's *known* that that's definitely what's happening in this case.

Comment: If there was not tunnelling in ammonia the energy levels in each of the two wells would be independent of one another, i.e. be single in each well, i.e. there would be no interaction between one half and the other, the wavefunction would not be able to pass from one well to the other, which is the signature of tunnelling. As there is interaction, there is the possibility of tunnelling,  the levels in each well are doubled and split in energy and this is confirmed by spectroscopic experiment. It is the only reasonable explanation.

Comment: continued. The theory is the same whether it's electrons or whatever tunnelling, it's just the extend of this that changes, being far less probable as the mass increases.

Comment: @porphyrin There are several possible ways think about going from initial to final state and trying to cover all of them in comments is probably "over-constrained" but until all possible explanations are addressed it's hard to say "it's the only..." I think an answer post would probably provide more space. Just for example though, what rules out the much lighter hydrogens from tunneling?

Comment: if I remember correctly from my undergraduate lectures, all saturated N centres (ammonia & amines) flip continually back and forth at a very high rate. This is the reason that a tertiary amine with 3 differing R groups is *not* chiral. This was always explained by the sp3 orbital (that the lone pair on the Nitrogen atom occupies) has a tiny probability of being on the opposite side of the N atom. This allows the N centre to invert with a low energetic barrier.

Comment: @uhoh You should consider the reduced mass of the system as the mass that tunnels. In a simplified picture, the hydrogen atoms are considered to move simultaneously with respect to the nitrogen atom and the reduced mass is given by $\mu_\text{red}=3m_\text{N}m_\text{H}/(m_\text{N}+3m_\text{H})\approx 2.5$ u, which is a relatively light and can easily tunnel. Another proof that the ammonia really tunnels is by comparing the [observed](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevA.9.12) splitting of NH$_3$ with that of ND$_3$ and NT$_3$ which follows exactly what you expect for tunneling.

Comment: The reason why QM tunneling often plays a role in masers based on molecules (in methanol, the hindered internal rotation of the OH group with respect to the CH$_3$ group also represents a tunneling motion), is that the tunneling splitting provides nearby energy levels of opposite parity which can be used to generate a population inversion in the upper component of the tunneling level which can decay to the lower level via dipole transitions providing the maser radiation.

Comment: @Paul I think you have everything ready to post an answer. It's really hard being on the receiving end of great insight compressed into SE comments. I wrote this a few years ago: [What is the overall positive result of leaving compressed answers as comments?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3559/16035). Probably "another proof" should really be "additional strong evidence". Anyway, all that needs to be answered is the question posted and based on your comments I think you have it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me expand a little on my earlier comment. If we only consider the inversion of the ammonia molecule (we ignore rotation and vibrations other than the inversion mode), the Schrödinger equation is given by
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu_\text{red}}\frac{\text{d}^2\psi{z}}{\text{d}z^2}+V(z)\psi(z)=E\psi(z),
$$
with $\mu_\text{red}$ the reduced mass and $z=d_\text{NH}\sin{\alpha}$, where $d_\text{NH}$ is the NH bond distance and $\alpha$ the so-called umbrella angle. The potential V(z) is shown in the [link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/132449/particle-in-a-box-with-different-barriers-between-two-molecules/132499#132499) given by porphyrin in one of his comments. Although the reduced mass does, in principle, depend on $\alpha$ (see Eq. 4 of [this](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.9.12) paper), the dependance is weak and we may consider that the hydrogen atoms move simultaneously with respect to the nitrogen atom. In this case
$$
\mu_\text{red}=\frac{3m_\text{H}m_\text{N}}{3m_\text{H}+m_\text{N}}\approx2.5\text{ u}.
$$
The tunneling does not change the center of mass (c.o.m.) of the molecule, so while the nitrogen moves up, the plane of hydrogen atoms moves down to ensure the stationary c.o.m. (and *vice versa*). I made the following animated gif at some point during my PhD (sorry for the watermark, but I've  had some negative experiences in the past):

[image]

The [first paper](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.41.313) - to my knowledge - that treats the tunneling of ammonia appeared already in 1932. The [first application](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01343196) of QM tunneling was done by Gamow appeared 4 years prior to the ammonia work and solved the mystery of the huge range of observed lifetimes of alpha emitters (20 orders of magnitude).

In the 1932 paper, Dennison and Uhlenbeck also derive the magnitude of the tunneling splitting as a function of the reduced mass
$$
E_\text{inv}=\frac{h\nu_0}{\pi}\exp\left \{-\frac{2\pi}{h}\int_\limits{-z_0}^{z_0}\left [2\mu_\text{red}\left (V(z)-E \right ) \right ]^{1/2} \right \},
$$
where $\pm z_0$ are the equilibrium positions corresponding to the potential minima, $\nu_0$ is the vibration frequency in one of the two wells and $E$ is the energy of the system with respect to the potential minimum. This expression is derived from the WKB approximation and it basically is the product of the tunneling probability with the frequency with which the reduced mass 'hits' the barrier. As can be seen from the formula, the tunneling frequency scales exponentially with the square root of the reduced mass, which is also observed experimentally. The following picture is taken from my thesis and basically a copy of Fig. 2 of [this](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.9.12) paper.

[image]

If the molecule would simple rotate instead of tunnel, the change in the energy splitting would be inversely proportional to the reduced mass (via the moment of inertia) and this is clearly not observed.

Comment: This is of course an excellent answer! I'm off to the library today to get these...

Comment: hmm... I'm not sure what happened but I don't seem to have followed through on this, So I'm off to the library today ***again*** @@ to get these...  ;-)